# Redirect sitemap.xml to a file in /assets/sitemap/ using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

If I have a subdomain, how can I redirect it's sitemap.xml to a file found in /assets/sitemap?

```
subdomain1.example.com/sitemap.xml -> /assets/sitemap/subdomain1.xml
subdomain2.example.com/sitemap.xml -> /assets/sitemap/subdomain2.xml
```

I used this static code but how to make it dynamic depending on subdomain name?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml /assets/sitemap/subdomain1.xml [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `RewriteCond` and capture subdomain name from there:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /assets/sitemap/%1.xml [L,NC]
```

Comment: Yes! It worked! Thank you @anubhava. However I noticed that you commented your RewriteCond line.

Comment: Good catch, yes that by mistake. It is corrected now.